# How to check element visibility independent of parent visibility (jQuery or not)

Tags: javascript, jquery

my first Question so please be patient. I have a container that holds a varying number of child elements like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">content</div>
    <div class="element">content</div>
    <div class="element">content</div>
</div>
```

**Quick Question:**
Is there a jQuery or plain JS way of checking whether an `element` container would be visible independent of the `parent` being visible?

Simply asking for

```
jQuery('.parent .element:visible').length
```

does **not** work.

**Background:** The `parent` container can be toggled, and the content of the child `element`s gets fetched by ajax requests and is filled when the response arrives. On every response I get, the child containers get specific classes indicating the type of the response, e.g. `available`, `unavailable` and some more. So the resulting DOM may look like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element available">content</div>
    <div class="element unavailable">content</div>
    <div class="element unavailable">content</div>
</div>
```

This is a module, that is used several times with different CSS files. So I do not control whether the CSS implementation actually hides `unavailable` elements because this is done only in CSS. And the container can be open, but does not have to. But I have to know if there would be visible elements inside of the container without opening it. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, if a parent is invisible, it's children are implicitly.

Comment: Yes thats true, but maybe there is a way to filter out the inherited styles or circumvent this problem nevertheless?

Comment: @Orbling Implicit, but they don't have the styling that says so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to do this if you have classes like available or unavailable. But this is how I would do it (so the actual visibility doesn't interfere with the child's visibility):

```
if (
    $('.element').css('display') != 'none' && 
    $('.element').css('visibility') != 'hidden'
) {
    // ...
}
```

In action:

http://jsfiddle.net/EbaMY/2/

Comment: And/or check the `visibility` style. You probably want to be checking for NOT invisible too

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works for me and does not change the parent. I need this because I do not know whether `unavailable` is visible or not in the CSS.

Comment: I still don't understand it, but I'm glad this does it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best answer, but I think it should work

```
  if ($('.parent').is(':visible')) {
        $('.element:visible')....//what you want to do
    }else{
       $('.parent').show()
       $('.element:visible')...//what you want to do again
       $('.parent').hide()
    }
```

Comment: +1 As the idea is an often used one, remove the inherited trait, check for it independently and then restore the original state.

Comment: Nice and simple solution. I did not try it out because i thought the parent container would be visible for a short time, but it works without flickering :) THX! I will accept @emergence answer, because it works without changing the parent.